# How to reference variable name using variable's values

Tags: java, variables, graphics

Okay. For my Computer Science Project we have to make a program or game that impresses our teacher. I've chosen Battleship, and using Netbeans Design UI I have made the basic outline for my UI. 

So Essentially one of my methods that sets a JPanel to blue when you assign a ship to it, i don't want to write 400 lines of code describing if statements for every single possible box they could assign their ship to, and i was wondering if there was a way to reference the value of a variable in the name of a JPanel. I'll show you what I mean.

So var is the location of the ship already retrieved from the User. pA1 would be Player's panel at A1.

```
public static void pSetShip(String var){
        var=("p"+var);
        if (var.equals("pA1")){
            pA1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        }
}
```

Is there any possible way instead of setting each individual box using if statements i could do this:

```
public static void pSetShip(String var){
        var=("p"+var);
        (VALUE OF VAR VARIABLE).setBackground(Color.BLUE);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: "don't want to write ... for every single possible box they could assign their ship to" -- that's why there are arrays and loops.  My 10-second guess at a design approach is a 20x20 array, each entry being an enumeration of all possible things that could occupy the cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, assuming they implement a common *interface*. **But** you will need to store them in something. Assuming they're of type `JComponent` I would use a `Map<String, JComponent>` like

```
static Map<String, JComponent> map = new HashMap<>();
static {
    map.put("pA1", pA1);
    // ... for all valid components.
}
```

Then you can use it like

```
public static void pSetShip(String var){
    map.get("p"+var).setBackground(Color.BLUE);
}
```